# ruby on rails selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'headless'
require 'nokogiri'

puts "start headless..."
headless = Headless.new
headless.start

puts "start selenium..."
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

I run this code, but this code don't work.

```
stack backtrace:: address not available(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
```

I run this code with firefox58, selenium-webdriver 3.9.0

what's the problem?